# MYSQL - output extra column based on a certain condition

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

At first, I want to apologize for providing such a weak title; I couldn't describe it in a better way.

Consider the following: We have three tables, one for `users`, one for `records` and one for `ratings`. The tables are quite self-explanatory but the schema for database is as following:

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_relations |
+---------------------+
| records             |
| ratings             |
| users               |
+---------------------+
```

The schema for `records` table is as following:

```
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(256)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year     | int(4)               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The schema for `users` table is as following:

```
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email    | varchar(256)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(256)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(256)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`ratings` table is, obvoiusly, where the ratings are stored among with the record_id and user_id and works as a relation table.

It's schema is as following:

```
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| record_id| smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rating   | int(1)               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, In my application, I have a search function that fetches records based on a certain keyword. The output should also include the average rating of a certain record and a total amount of ratings per record. This can be accomplished by following query:

```
SELECT re.id, re.title, re.year, ROUND(avg(ra.rating)) as avg_rate,
COUNT(ra.record_id) as total_times_rated
FROM records re
LEFT JOIN ratings ra ON ra.record_id = re.id
GROUP BY re.id;
```

which will give me the following output:

```
+----+------------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
| id | title                  | year | avg_rate | total_times_rated |
+----+------------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
|  1 | Test Record 1          | 2008 |        3 |                 4 |
|  2 | Test Record 2          | 2012 |        2 |                 4 |
|  3 | Test Record 3          | 2003 |        3 |                 4 |
|  4 | Test Record 4          | 2012 |        3 |                 3 |
|  5 | Test Record 5          | 2003 |        2 |                 3 |
|  6 | Test Record 6          | 2006 |        2 |                 3 |
+----+------------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
```

**Question:**

Now, here comes the tricky part, at least for me. Within my app, you can search records whether signed in or not and if signed in, I'd also like to include the user's own rating value in the above query.

I know that I can run a conditional to check whether user is signed in or not by reading the session value and execute a corresponding query based on that. I just don't know how to include that individual rating value of a certain user to the above query.

Comment: How do you calculate user's rating? Is it `SUM` of all ratings of matching records?

Comment: It is an individual value. Every time user rates a record, it will be stored in the `ratings` table (record_id, user_id and the actual rate)

Comment: The objective of this would be that user can review his/her own rating value if he/she has rated a record based on the keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add user's rating in the result by adding a `SELECT` query in columns:

```
SELECT re.id, re.title, re.year, ROUND(avg(ra.rating)) as avg_rate,
COUNT(ra.record_id) as total_times_rated,
(SELECT rating FROM ratings WHERE user_id = ? AND record_id = re.id) as user_rating
FROM records re
LEFT JOIN ratings ra ON ra.record_id = re.id
GROUP BY re.id;
```

We can get the `user_id` from session and pass it to this query in order to generate `user_rating` column in the result.

Assuming user can rate a record multiple times, I have used `SUM`. If not, we can remove it from the query.

**Update**

If you don't want `GROUP BY` to consider that value then you can wrap the existing query into another query and add a column to it, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.year, a.avg_rate, a.total_times_rated,
(SELECT rating FROM ratings WHERE user_id = ? AND record_id = a.id) as user_rating
FROM (SELECT re.id as id, re.title as title, re.year as year, ROUND(avg(ra.rating)) as avg_rate,
COUNT(ra.record_id) as total_times_rated
FROM records re
LEFT JOIN ratings ra ON ra.record_id = re.id
GROUP BY re.id) a;
```

Comment: Just tried it, returns following error: `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`. I assume it's because there can be multiple records user has rated and thus giving the error. 

And yes, user cannot rate a single record multiple times, that's why I removed the `SUM` from your answer.

Comment: Added one more condition in the query, try now?

Comment: Well yeah, now I do get the `user_rating` value if user has rated a record and `NULL` if not. However, now it fetches `total_times_recorded` and `avg_rate` from one record and output it on all records which didn't happened before. Strange...

Comment: Ah okay, I have added another query to the answer, can you try again?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works just as I wanted it to work. Cheers, mate :) Those subqueries can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)